# Advice on proxying CSS and JS with a Node.js "proxy" server

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, dom-manipulation

I have a working server for entering a URL in a query parameter, it fetches the page and sends it back. The problem is, the CSS links don't always work because generally CSS is fetched from the source by the HTML `<link rel="stylesheet">` tag. Is there a way I can fetch the CSS from the URL and send it in a `<style>` tag?

I'd like to be able to do this with JavaScript as well, but it is not a requirement.

Additionally, as a "nice-to-have", is it possible to change anchor href tags to change the query parameter instead of URL itself?
`privatedomain.com/page?url=<urlhere>` is the URL structure I have, and would like it to be able to redirect from something like `privatedomain.com/page?url=http://www.google.com` to `privatedomain.com/page?url=http://www.google.com/search?q=hmm+yes`

Really just a thing I'm doing for fun and trying to get it to work, if I asked this question incorrectly, I'm sorry, it's my first time asking here, thanks!

Comment: The second question about changing anchor tags would be best submitted as a separate question.  Best to keep your questions granular than to put too many in a single post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parse the document, find `<link rel="stylesheet">`, extract the relative path to CSS from there.

Then you can concatenate the relative path with the root of your `<urlhere>`. Then replace a link inside `<link rel="stylesheet">` with your combined path.

Example:
privatedomain.com/page?url=http://example.com/foo/bar.html

in `foo.html` you have `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles.css">`

You need to make `const absoulteCssPath = 'http://example.com' + '/styles.css'`; and then replace `/styles.css` inside  `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles.css">` with  your `absoulteCssPath`.